# Which matrices commute with this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering which $2 \times 2$ matrices commute with the following matrix?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: The numbers may be different but the technique will be the same as in the linked question.

Comment: Sure, I can just brute force, but I hoped that for this particular one there was a nice trick

Comment: "*I hoped ... there was a nice trick*"  The multiplication takes almost no time whatsoever and no effort to keep track of things with the large number of zeroes involved.  You don't like "brute force" but that is like complaining about evaluating $5\times 10$ "by brute force."  This isn't brute force so much as it is simply calculating.

Comment: Yes, you *could* do something smarter and faster but more technically heavy talking about Jordan blocks and minimal polynomials and such, and that may be a good idea for much larger matrices... but for such a small matrix like this one there is no benefit (*apart from practice for the harder problems*) in doing so.

Comment: It is a non-derogatory matrix (it's the companion matrix of $x^2$). Hence it commutes only with polynomials in it.

Answer (score 0):

Call the given matrix $A$, denote by $e_{1},e_{2}$ the canonical basis. Then A is uniquely determined by:
$Ae_{1}=0,Ae_{2}=e_{1}$. Let B be a matrix commuting with A, then $ABe_{1}=BAe_{1}=0$,that is, $Be_{1}$ lies in the kernel of A, So $Be_{1}=te_{1}$,now $Be_2=ve_{1}+we_{2}$,so $A(ve_{1}+we_{2}) =te_{1}$
So $w=t$, so the set of matrices commuting with A has the following form :
$B= \begin{pmatrix} t & v \\ 0 & t \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Please don't answer "no effort" questions.